# Why does my Keras model.predict output 2 values instead of 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Why my `model.predict` outputs 2 values instead of 1?

```
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Flatten(input_shape=[139, 28]))
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))  #input=number of inputs from data; 32=number of neurons in the layer
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64)


print("Generate predictions")
predictions = model.predict(x_train[:1])
print(x_train.shape)
print (predictions)
print("predictions shape:", predictions.shape)`
```

And I got the following output:

```
Epoch 1/10
```

---

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 16>()
14 model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
15 # fit model
---> 16 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
17
18 #print(len(model.layers))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
50   try:
51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' defined at (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in 
app.launch_new_instance()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
self.io_loop.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
self._run_once()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
handle._run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in 
lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
ret = callback()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
self.ctx_run(self.run)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
yielded = self.gen.send(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
self.do_execute(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
result = self._run_cell(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
return runner(coro)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in *pseudo_sync_runner
coro.send(None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async*=asy)):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "", line 16, in <cell line: 16>
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
return self.compiled_loss(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in **call**
loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in **call**
losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call
return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2078, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
return backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5660, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
Received a label value of 1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
[[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3244]

Comment: `model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))` what does the 2 stand for in your opinion?...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as a non-issue, stemming from a fundamental misunderstanding of the posted code and the underlying very basic principles of the related ML theory/methodology.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the last sentence to 'model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))'. And I got the above error when it compile the model. Any further advice?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 units in last SoftMax layer. So, there will be 2 outputs.
`0.36325565` and `0.6367443` are two different outputs.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the last sentence to 'model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))'. And I got the above error when it compile the model. Any further advice?

Comment: Change your loss to "categorical_crossentropy"